# Remove default select drop down

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to remove the select default drop down when applying your own? Currently I'm using a background image for mine:

```
.select-custom {
  background-image: url ('/images/select-arrow.png')
}
```

Is there a way to override the default, for FF/IE for example?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to have a look on the **[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)** jQuery plugin which changes the appearance of the select tag. 
You can customize it further to achieve exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `<select>` element in a `<div>` element. The objective is to set the `<select>` element just wider than the `<div>` element so that the arrow becomes not visible. You can then change the arrow using the `background:` property on the `<div>` element in CSS.

```
<div class="custom">
    <select>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Refer to this tutorial for a detailed description:

http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/